# close app when InAppPurchase add to delphi xe7 form

Tags: android, delphi, in-app-purchase

Adding a **TInAppPurchase** component to a project crashes the app after starting on the device. Even when **FMX.InAppPurchase** is added to the uses clause the app crashes on the device. This error doesn't occur in the simulator...

I am using Android version 4.2 and 2.3 and show this error when debug running,

> project.apk raised exception class EIAPEexception with message
>   'problem setting up in-app-billing : IabResult : Error checking for
>   billing v3 support. (response :Billing Unavailable)'

Comment: What Android version?

Comment: Android version 4.2 and 2.3

Comment: Have you enabled the permissions for `Vending billing (In-app Billing)` as described in the documentation? http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html In Delphi, this is in Project Options > Uses Permissions.

Comment: of course , checked Vending billing (In-app Billing)

Comment: Could it be that you enabled it for debug only but not for release? Or in general one configuration but not another?

Comment: debug and release,Both of

Comment: show this error when debug ruining, project.apk raised exception class EIAPEexception with message 'problem setting up in-app-billing : IabResult : Error checking for billing v3 support. (response :Billing Unavailable)'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I provide a information about the problem from comment