# Delphi FMX.InAppPurchase - crashes app when there is no google account on device

Tags: android, delphi, crash

When I add FMX.InAppPurchase to the uses section, the app will crash on start when there is no google account on the device. So when somebody will install my app and will not have the google account on the device,  my app will crashes immediately on start with comment: "the application has been stopped"

```
 unit Unit1;

    interface

   uses
     FMX.InAppPurchase, System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, 
     System.Classes,      
     System.Variants,FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics,  
     FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,FMX.Colors, Math, FMX.Objects, FMX.Effects,  
     FMX.Layouts, GameAudioManager, FMX.Media, System.IOUtils,  
     system.SyncObjs,   
     FMX.Memo, System.dateutils, System.Diagnostics, FMX.Edit,  
     FMX.Filter.Effects, FMX.VirtualKeyboard, FMX.Platform, FMX.Ani,
     FMX.WebBrowser, FMX.Controls.Presentation, IdBaseComponent, 
     IdComponent,
     IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHttp, System.Actions, FMX.ActnList,
     FMX.StdActns, FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions,    
     FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances,  
     FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base,  
     FMX.ListView, System.StrUtils,FMX.ScrollBox;

{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  ,Androidapi.JNI.Os,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge
{$ENDIF};
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? Or a stack trace from the crash?

Comment: Just when I put FMX.InAppPurchase in uses section the app crash on start with statement: "the application has been stopped". Of course when i add google account to my device everything works fine.

Comment: Looks like this question: [close app when InAppPurchase add to delphi xe7 form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952265/close-app-when-inapppurchase-add-to-delphi-xe7-form) - but without the complete error message nobody can tell. And: which delphi version do you use? Is there a bug report for this?